# Image magick create triangle

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagick

How can I create a triangle which looks like this using image magick:

[image]

and this one

[image]

I tried following command but it did not work properly,

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill blue -stroke black -draw "path 'M 25,60 L 25,10 L 70,10 L 20,55 Z' " output.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill skyblue -stroke black -draw "path 'M 10,50 L 90,10 L 90,90 Z' " output.png
```

[image]

Create the other one with `-flop`:

```
convert output.png -flop output2.png
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use a poly line. Out of interest I have not seen Letters in with the points before.

Comment: @Bonzo It's just the `SVG` method... https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation

Comment: Thanks alot again :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell how would you create the second image without that flop method?

Comment: Like I showed in the answer... `convert output.png -flop output2.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry I mean without

Comment: `convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill skyblue -stroke black -draw "path 'M 90,50 L 10,10 L 10,90 Z' " output.png`